# Use ng-model to mark selected items in dropdown with ng-repeat and ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I'm trying to achieve is to print in rows information about server and permissions granted on that server. For that I'm using array `displayServers` that stores arrays of servers that can be selected and in each iteration of `ng-repeat` I'm creating a dropdown with those servers. I also want in each iteration to mark selected server with `ng-model` that corresponds to JS object that stores information about server and corresponding permissions granted.

The object that stores info with server and permissions looks like this:

```
var modalUser = {
       Permissions: {
            server1: ['admin', 'developer'],
            server2: ['developer'],
            serverN: ['permissionN'] 
       }
}

var displayServers = [
     ['server1', 'server2', 'serverN'],
     ['server1', 'server2', 'serverN']   
]
```

And the HTML looks like this

```
   <tr ng-repeat="serverArray in displayServers track by $index" ng-if="server[0] != 'removed'">
        <td class="col-md-2">
        <div style="margin-top: 8px" >
            <select class="selectpicker server"
                    ng-options="serverName as serverName for serverName in serverArray track by serverName"
                    ng-model="modalUser.Permissions[serverName]">
            <option style="display: none" value="">Select server</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can set the ng-model to simple property and then call a function on ng-change to do the logic, which is to set "modalUser.Permissions[serverName]" by code.

Hope that helps !

**UPDATED**

```
    $scope.checkIfPresentInPermissions = funtions(serverName){
    // logic to check if server name is present in modalUser.Permissions[serverName]
    };



      <tr ng-repeat="serverArray in displayServers track by $index" ng-if="server[0] != 'removed'">
        <td class="col-md-2">
        <div style="margin-top: 8px" >
            <select class="selectpicker server"                   
                    ng-model="modalUser.SelectedServer">
            <option style="display: none" value="">Select server</option>

<option  ng-repeat="serverName as serverName for serverName in serverArray track by serverName" value="{{serverName }}" selected="checkIfPresentInPermissions(serverName)" >{{serverName }}</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        </td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want to achieve. When the dropdowns with servers are rendered I want to mark the server as selected if it is defined in modalUser.Permissions property. That's why I'm trying to use ng-model to detect if server is defined in modalUser.

Comment: Can there be more than one selected?

Comment: Yes, there is a table that contains row per server and in every row, there is a select that contains all servers with one marked as selected according to data stored in modalUser

Comment: So if the server name is present in Permissions, it should be selected?

Comment: Yes exactly. This is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Danish](https://stackexchange.com/users/4527679/danish) you showed me the way to resolve my issue. What I did was:

```
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in modalUser.gS_Permissions track by key">
          <td class="col-md-2">
              <div style="margin-top: 8px" >
                  <select class="selectpicker server">
                       <option style="display: none" value="">Select server</option>
                       <option ng-repeat="server in servers track by server"
                               value="{{server}}"
                               ng-selected="checkIfPresentInPermissions(server, key);">{{server}}</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

Where `checkIfPresentInPermissions(server)` looks like this

```
 $scope.checkIfPresentInPermissions = function(server, key){
        return server === key;
    }
```